# Sudo nautilus gives Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, nautilus

I have just updated my OS from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS. When I tried to run nautilus as root by using `sudo nautilus`, I get the error

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4410): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:12:51.995: cannot open display: :10.0
```

This never occurred in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm trying to avoid reinstalling nautilus as much as possible to avoid breaking more things, but am running out ideas on what is wrong here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently the solution on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209746/how-to-resolve-no-protocol-specified-for-su-user/417233#417233) is able to solve my problem.

```
xhost + local:
```

Comment: This means that any other local user is allowed to run programs in your X session, however network connections will not be allowed. So it's fine, provided you are the only local user, or you trust all the other local users.

Comment: as well this works too `xhost si:localuser:root` adding `localuser:root being added to access control list`